# How to extract icon using powershell - resulting file is not windows icon file

Tags: powershell, icons

I have this simple script - which seems to be how every search I find tells me to extract an icon for use:

```
$Format = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Icon

$Source = 'C:\Windows\System32\DeviceProperties.exe'
[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($Source).ToBitmap().Save("c:\temp\extracted.ico",$Format)
```

Problem being that the resulting file is not a Windows icon file. As evidenced when you try to apply this icon to a shortcut or similar I receive this Windows error:

> The file C:\Temp\extracted contains no icons
>
> Choose an icon from the list or specify a diferent file

I'm assuming here it's because the result is a bitmap rather than an icon format.

The question is - how to convert this to a proper icon file ready for use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same limitation a long time ago and gave up, I believe.

However, this one looks promising - a pre-made module to export, and it supposedly supports .ico format.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-Icon-from-DLL-and-9d309047

I didn't test it, so I hope they didn't just rename the .bmp to .ico (because then it would probably not work either).

Comment: Ah yes, I'd completely forgotten about that module which I've used in the past - it does work properly, just tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The exported file: `c:\temp\extracted.ico` is a png file, not a ico file. I haven't found a way to convert this with powershell to ico format, either. But [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) e.g. can do this job.

Do the following:

1. Open that file in gimp with (*File / Open...*)
2. Click on *Export as...*
3. Change file extension from *.png* to *.ico* (if necessary)
4. Click on *Export* button
5. *Export Icon as Windows Icon* window appears, click on *Export* button (or adjust settings, if necessary)

This will convert the file format from png to ico and you won't lose transparency.

Answer (score 0):

An icon file is a file that contains many bitmap images (I think at some point they were 7). When trying to create an ico in GIMP for example you must put 7 bitmaps into it, each in it's own layer.
I assume you should use something different than ToBitmap.

PS: I don't have access to a Windows machine to actually try your powershell script/command and I don't have enough reputation to just comment.